# ACE model in R's `lmekin` package

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, genetics

I am trying to run an ACE twin genetics model in `R` using the package `lmekin`. I am trying to run the ACE model as described in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3129472/). My code looks something like the following:

```
library(coxme)
require(nlme)
library(kinship2)
library(Matrix)

# Read in additive genetic Kinship matrix
KinshipA <- # Read from csv kinship matrix of size (num subjects by num subjects)
KinshipA <- as.matrix(KinshipA)

# Read in common environmental Kinship matrix
KinshipC <- # Read from csv kinship matrix of size (num subjects by num subjects)
KinshipC <- as.matrix(KinshipC)

# Add dimension names
dimnames(KinshipA)[[1]] <- as.list(subjectID)
dimnames(KinshipA)[[2]] <- as.list(subjectID)
dimnames(KinshipC)[[1]] <- as.list(subjectID)
dimnames(KinshipC)[[2]] <- as.list(subjectID)

m <- lmekin(y~x+(1|subjectID),varlist=list(KinshipA,KinshipC))
```

My code is erroring and I am recieving this error:

```
Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  internal_chm_factor: Cholesky factorization failed
In addition: Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file ../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431
```

I understand this error is caused because some of the zero-valued eigenvalues have become machine-error level negative values and the cholesky decomposition used by `lmekin` is failing. My question is not about this. My question instead is does this seem like a valid approach for running the ACE model? Basically; am I doing it right? Also, if I am, is there an alternative way to do this in `R` instead?